# Android C4droid Sfml not rendering anything after minimizing and reopening program

Tags: android, c++, rendering, sfml

I am using the Sfml library on C4droid which has official sfml support. Everything works just fine, I can run the program normally and it renders graphics normally. But after i like minimize the app for a second and then open it back up again, for some reason it doesn't render anything at all, not even the window. Although everything else in the program runs normally like the sound,touch input, calculations etc. And I know it's not because C4droid is doing something wrong because every other graphics library i tried doesn't have that problem. Only sfml has it. I even tried it with Cxxdroid and I get the same problem.

I ran the sample programs so it's not a coding error. I tried using the the onlostfocus event to reload the files after it loses focus, I tried using only sfml shapes and no textures. But still the same thing happened. But after I tried to create a new window onlostfocus by using window.create(), It actually did render the new window even after minimizing and reopening but it only did that and didn't render/draw anything.

Is there a reason why it is happening and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION!

I went to the sfml discord server and a really NICE person helped me out. All you need to do is just window.setActive(false) on lost focus and window.setActive(true) on gained focus AND IT WORKS FLAWLESSLY!!!

Comment: `window.setActive(false)` on lost focus seems to be enough to make it work. Question is why does it work? Can you ask your Nice guy to explain what actually going on ?